# How can I change iframe src by clicking on different divs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

So I have five different div containers, and one iframe. I need to change src of iframe depending on which div I click. They're youtube links, so each time I click on particular div, iframe src should be changed.
Divs, clicking on which iframe should be changed:

[image]

Iframe:
[image]

Html code of iframe:

```
<div class="full">
                <iframe id="iframe" class="responsive_frame" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/K0u_kAWLJOA"></iframe>
            </div>
```

I've found some kind of solution, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var locations = ["https://www.youtube.com/embed/K0u_kAWLJOA", 
                    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/c7nRTF2SowQ", 
                    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/6LOD-pwJY6E",
                    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/8X2kIfS6fb8", 
                    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/p5yUKjOOWvM"
                ];
      var currentIndex = 0;
      var len = locations.length;
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.preview', function(){
            currentIndex = this.attr("id") == "1" ? 
            currentIndex < len - 1 ? ++currentIndex : 0 : 
            currentIndex > 0 ? --currentIndex : len - 1;

        $('#iframe').attr('src', locations[currentIndex]);
    });
        })
```

So basically, div has preview class, so jquery should activate a function when div with .preview class is clicked, and then, given IDs of divs, it should change the src of iframe, but it doesn't seem to work.

Edit:
Ok, so i made a completely new page and tried @Rana method, and it still didn't work in my browser, so i went to console and next errors showed up there:
[image]

So I'm not sure, maybe it has something to do with loading youtube links from javascript code?

Comment: Hi ! Can you post the error message you get ? I do, and suspect a `cross-origin` issue, ie you are not allowed to embed this external content.

Comment: hi @Philippe! Yes, i edited and added the errors, but I have no idea what's the problem, maybe it has something to do with youtube?
and i also deleted inside function and added alert('...') to check if the function works at all, but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of changing `src` on click of buttons and every time changed `src` is displayed.

- First `src` values are provided in a `array`
- Now looped through all the tags with class `.srcChanger` and added event listener which actives on `click` .
- Then function is executed which takes value from `array` according to `i` th value of tag

```js
var locations = ["https://www.youtube.com/embed/K0u_kAWLJOA",
  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/c7nRTF2SowQ",
  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/6LOD-pwJY6E",
  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/8X2kIfS6fb8",
  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/p5yUKjOOWvM"
];

var btnSrc = document.getElementsByClassName("srcChanger");
for (let i = 0; i < btnSrc.length; i++) {
  btnSrc[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("responsive_frame")[0].src = locations[i];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = locations[i];
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <iframe id="iframe" class="responsive_frame" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/K0u_kAWLJOA"></iframe>
</div>
<button class="srcChanger">Btn1</button>
<button class="srcChanger">Btn2</button>
<button class="srcChanger">Btn3</button>
<button class="srcChanger">Btn4</button>
<button class="srcChanger">Btn5</button>


<div id="demo"></div>
```

[Here is the working example of above code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GV2JY18SCMAJ)

Comment: This is setting the `src` on the first button which doesn't make sense. Should be targeting the iframe instead

Comment: Yes @charlietfl thanks for telling . By mistake I used the class of btns

Comment: hi, @charlietfl! will looping through divs work, or i can do it only with <button>? i did the same thing but with divs, getting div class by getElementByClassName, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Yes it will work with `div` also . You can try a change

Comment: ok, i made a new page as in your example, but there're some errors which i added to the post
but there's something wrong with function, i deleted main body of function and added alert('.....') to just check if it works, but for some reason it doesn't even display the message on screen

Comment: Here is link to the working code : https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GV2JY18SCMAJ  @Carl

Comment: woah, thank you, i guess the problem was that i inserted <script> in the beginning of body, and not in the end
so now i just have to figure out how to use it from another file
thank you very much! @Rana

Comment: No problem , happy to help @Carl