# Refused to display video

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, youtube, prismic.io

I know that there is already an answer for this, but I have 'embed' in the URL and it is not working. I have tried using 'watch', I have copied the URL directly from the source, I have deleted all of the styles, etc. There are about 7 videos total in all of the slides and the first one loads and works, but all the videos after it do not. All the slides are getting the content from Prismic.io.

I get the error:
Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

and my code is:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
   <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" 
     src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m1mHOcNilag?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" 
     allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Sometimes this error will show up with it:
"The service worker navigation preload request was cancelled before 'preloadResponse' settled. If you intend to use 'preloadResponse', use waitUntil() or respondWith() to wait for the promise to settle."

Just throwing this in there, not sure if it has any effect, but I also get this warning in the console: "chromewebdata/:7290 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated."

Comment: Your code is working fine you can see in the link here : https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GV5XLEOP1PSK . A similar question's link is : https://stackoverflow.com/q/69417780/16846346

Comment: The code is working, but it's not displaying. When the video is supposed to show it says "www.youtube.com refused to connect." on a gray background.

Comment: @Kassie try removing this parameters from the URL `?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0`. If the problem persists, check if the video(s) that have this problem can be embed.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I tried that and had no luck. In Youtube, the video is checked to allow embedding.

Comment: @Kassie check the `Network` tab - press F12 key in your browser - and reload the page. It *might* be possible the video is locked somehow or your webpage/domain is blocked. Also, this issue happens with this video in particular? can you please try with other video(s)?

Comment: I just tried sharing the video from youtube and selecting embed, and it is still not connecting.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I tried changing to a random youtube video, not one of mine, and it's not loading either. Could it be a timeout issue?

Comment: @Kassie probably, or maybe some blocked content to your domain. I'm not familiar with Prismic.io - have you contact for support? - you can also search if a post with a similar case to yours has been reported on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%20status:open).